# Access protected members in C++

Tags: c++

How can I access protected members declared in class 'SecondDlg' within class 'ChooseDirDlg', if at all? Below are the class declarations:

```
class CChooseDirDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
CChooseDirDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);    // standard constructor



class SecondDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
SecondDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
```

Would changing the constructor to take a derived instance of one class solve the problem? And if so, how could I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from it

```
class CChooseDirDlg : public SecondDlg
{}
```

Declare the class as friend

```
class SecondDlg : public CDialog
{
    friend class CChooseDirDlg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `CChooseDirDlg` as `friend` inside `SecondDlg`.
This will grant `CChooseDirDlg` access to *all* members of `SecondDlg`, even the private ones.

I wouldn't have minded if C++ had implemented an `acquaintance` acces modifier to grant access to protected members ;-)

Comment: Thanks mate...this site is so helpful